# Jackson XML deserialization fails on no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I try to parse XML with Jackson. I have generated java DTO from XSD, so no camel case is used and the naming convention would not make sense there.

Beans:

```
FINSTABean bean = xmlMapper.readValue(file, FINSTABean.class);

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class FINSTABean {
    @JsonProperty("STA_VER")
    String STA_VER;
    @JsonProperty("FINSTA03")
    List<FINSTA03Bean> FINSTA03BeanList;
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class FINSTA03Bean {
    @JsonProperty("S28_CISLO_VYPISU")
    String S28_CISLO_VYPISU;
    String S25_CISLO_UCTU;
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<FINSTA>
    <STA_VER>01.0000</STA_VER>
    <FINSTA03>
        <S28_CISLO_VYPISU>10</S28_CISLO_VYPISU>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.lelifin.alfa.parsers.csob_xml.FINSTA03Bean` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('10')
 at [Source: (File); line: 5, column: 29] (through reference chain: com.lelifin.alfa.parsers.csob_xml.FINSTABean["FINSTA03"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1353) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:311) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1495) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:197) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:355) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.XmlDeserializationContext.readRootValue(XmlDeserializationContext.java:91) ~[jackson-dataformat-xml-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
```

Why does it says that it cannot deserialize "10"? Is it some Lombok setter or constructor incompatibility?

If I remove `<FINSTA03>` sub element, I am able to properly load that `FINSTABean`.

Comment: You can read the very issue by this: `no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('10')`. It means that `@NoArgsConstructor` for class `FINSTA03Bean` is not enough in combination with setters and getters - a constructor is needed here which sets all the attributes as soon as an instance is created.

Comment: I have added AllArgsConstructor but it failed with the same error. If it was related, why would it fail on gthe first property and not after the last property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is about the `FINSTA03BeanList` list because you are not annotating it with the specific [`JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) annotation causing the error due to the fact that jackson library misinterpretes your list as a single property. You can also use the xml specific [`JacksonXmlProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html) annotation instead of `JsonProperty` for properties:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FINSTABean {
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    String STA_VER;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "FINSTA03")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    List<FINSTA03Bean> FINSTA03BeanList;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FINSTA03Bean {
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    String S28_CISLO_VYPISU;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried to post the same finding in the morning, but it's gone. So I accept yours.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Glad to have helped.